# How to refer to a value in different row without adding a new column?

Tags: sql, data-structures

I have purchase order data aggregated by items and month with the item's price for that month. I need to look back for the last month's price to find the difference in price. Not every item is purchased in every month (e.g. March 2020 is missing).

My approach is to add a new column to save the last month price, then add another new column to calculate the price change. But this may fail to be first normal form? Is there a better approach in terms of data structure?

Eventually this table will be fed into Power BI to report out the price changes by item. We want to do the calculations in SQL rather than in Power BI, and let Power BI focus on creating visuals.

| Item | Month | Current price | Last month price | Price change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | Jan 2020 | $1 | - | - |
| Item 1 | Feb 2020 | $1.50 | $1 | $0.50 |
| Item 1 | Apr 2020 | $1.75 | - | - |
| Item 1 | May 2020 | $2 | $1.75 | $0.25 |

Comment: Neither of those columns seem necessary (or, if they are, they could probably be calculated columns or part of a view). It likely makes more sense to use `lag` to get the previous month's price and subtraction to get the difference.

Comment: What are the data types of your columns?

Comment: You can add two date columns, validFrom and ValidTo(null value means current price). Each time you insert a new value for the item, update the validTo from the previous row and validFrom from the new row with the same timestamp. Google Slowly Changing Dimension for other strategies.